# Fade in, Fade out not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to get this working.

```
$('#disclaimer').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

from http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1/.

This is my code

```html
<style>

#disclaimer{
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin-top: 0px !important;
 position: fixed;
 float: left;
 bottom: 0 !important;
     z-index:3;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 font-weight: normal !important;
 border-top: 0px solid black;
}

#disclaimer p{
 font: 1.1em "Futura",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: normal !important;
 line-height: 100%;
 text-align: center !important;
   -webkit-transition-property: font-size;
 -moz-transition-property: font-size;
 transition-property: font-size;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
 transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
 -webkit-transition-timing function: linear, ease-in;
 -moz-transition-timing function: linear, ease-in; 
 transition-timing function: linear, ease-in; 
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#disclaimer a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-right: 18px;
 padding-left: 18px;
}
</style>

<div id="disclaimer">
<p>
  Text
</p>
</div>
```

With the script in the footer over at http://www.adress.com/ (the page im working on). Still, it has no visible effect. Anyone has any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: You have no trigger for it. Do you want it to happen when you click? When you scroll? When it comes into view? Please expand your question.

Comment: I want #disclaimer to fade in when you enter the site and then fade out  like on http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1/.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is showing the error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` in the JS console (always worth checking), so you're incorrectly including JQuery.

Either include it from a CDN, or host it on your server.

To include from a CDN include this before your script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: Ah, you are correct, you're using what appears to be a very old version of JQuery, along with the JQuery migrate plugin. I would still suggest that is this is a new site, upgrading to the latest JQuery would probably be the solution (and removing the duplicate old versions)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `slow` you will see visual effect

```
$('#overlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Tried. Still nothing. It is set to slow if you enter the site now.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> You have a lot of error in your page, take a look at the console.

I saw that you call jQuery 1.11, jQuery 1.12, and the migrate plugin, try to call it one time.

Like now using **jQuery** instead of **$**, should work, but fix it

```
jQuery('#disclaimer').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: There we go. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: none;` from `#disclaimer`

Comment: On http://jsfiddle.net/SUBnz/1/ display:none; is used. Now I have removed display: none. but then the div appears at all times (the script doesnt fade it out).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!